# Cannot select content on dvd in Acidrip

Tags: lubuntu, dvd

I am using Acidrip 0. 14 and Lubuntu 14. 04. Typed in '/dev/sr0' in the video source path field and at the bottom left corner it says 'DVD read ok' but nothing shows up in the large window under the path. What are the correct pieces that have to be in place first in order for Acidrip to function? Why does content not appear in the large window under the path field? Acidrip did work under Lubuntu 13. 10 the one time I used it but not under 14. 04.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the package lsdvd included in Ubuntu. The bug is fixed in Debian (where the package originated), but did not make its way to Ubuntu yet. Replace the lsdvd package with the highest numbered version of the amd64 package at: http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lsdvd/. As of March 2015, this was "lsdvd_0.17-1_amd64.deb".

Comment: Your link is dead. Has anything changed?

Comment: On Mint 17.1 this was also the answer (July 2016, version described above was still the newest)

Answer (score 0):

uninstall lsdvd 0.16 4 and install lsdvd 0.16 3 in http://packages.ubuntu.com/ (saucy)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This seems to be suggesting a downgrade. That seems like a viable answer in this case. Could be better worded but still an answer.

Comment: Elio, thanks for the answer, could you please provide more detail(steps to uninstall/install the software mentioned to make this a useful answer.